# C++ functions and loops

Tags: c++, function, loops

I have to write a program that simulates an ice cream cone vendor. The user inputs the number of cones, and for each cone, the user inputs the number of scoops, then the flavor(a single character) for each scoop. At the end, the total price is listed. For the pricing, **1** scoop costs `2.00`, **2** scoops costs `3.00` and each scoop **after 2** costs `.75`.

I'm having trouble with the pricing. The correct price is displayed if the user only wants one cone.

```
/*
* icecream.cpp
*
*  Created on: Sep 14, 2014
*      Author:
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void welcome() {
    cout << "Bob and Jackie's Ice Cream\n";
    cout << "1 scoop - $1.50\n";
    cout << "2 scoops - $2.50;\n";
    cout << "Each scoop after 2 - $.50\n";
    cout << "Ice Cream Flavors: Only one input character for each flavor.\n";
}

bool checkscoops(int scoops) {
    int maxscoops = 5;

    if ((scoops > maxscoops) || (scoops < 1))

        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

bool checkcones(int cones) {
    int maxcones = 10;

    if ((cones > maxcones) || cones < 1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

int price(int cones, int numberofscoops) {
    float cost = 0.00;
    {
        if (numberofscoops == 5) {
            cost = cost + 5 + (.75 * 3);
        }
        if (numberofscoops == 4) {
            cost = cost + 5 + (.75 * 2);
        }
        if (numberofscoops == 3) {
            cost = cost + 5.75;
        }
        if (numberofscoops == 2) {
            cost = cost + 5.00;
        }
        if (numberofscoops == 1) {
            cost = cost + 2.00;
        }
    }
    cout << "Total price is:  " << cost << endl;
}
int buildcone(int numcones) {
    char flav1, flav2, flav3, flav4, flav5;
    int numberofscoops;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numcones; i++) {
        cout << "Enter the amount of scoops you wish to purchase. (5 max): ";
        cin >> numberofscoops;
        checkscoops(numberofscoops);
        while (checkscoops(numberofscoops) == false) {
            cout << "You are not allowed to buy more than 5 scoops and you "
                    "cannot buy less than one scoop. Please try again.\n";
            cout << "How many scoops would you like?(5 max): ";
            cin >> numberofscoops;
            checkcones(numberofscoops);
        }

        cout << "You are buying " << numberofscoops
             << " scoops of ice cream.\n";
        if (numberofscoops == 5) {
            cout << "Enter flavor 1: ";
            cin >> flav1;
            cout << "Enter flavor 2: ";
            cin >> flav2;
            cout << "Enter flavor 3: ";
            cin >> flav3;
            cout << "Enter flavor 4: ";
            cin >> flav4;
            cout << "Enter flavor 5: ";
            cin >> flav5;
            cout << " ( " << flav1 << " )/" << endl;
            cout << " ( " << flav2 << " )" << endl;
            cout << " ( " << flav3 << " )" << endl;
            cout << " ( " << flav4 << " )" << endl;
            cout << " ( " << flav5 << " )" << endl;
            cout << "  \\"
                 << " /" << endl << "   |" << endl;
        }
        if (numberofscoops == 4) {
            cout << "Enter flavor 1: ";
            cin >> flav1;
            cout << "Enter flavor 2: ";
            cin >> flav2;
            cout << "Enter flavor 3: ";
            cin >> flav3;
            cout << "Enter flavor 4: ";
            cin >> flav4;
            cout << " ( " << flav1 << " )" << endl;
            cout << " ( " << flav2 << " )" << endl;
            cout << " ( " << flav3 << " )" << endl;
            cout << " ( " << flav4 << " )" << endl;
            cout << "  \\"
                 << " /" << endl << "   |" << endl;
        }
        if (numberofscoops == 3) {
            cout << "Enter flavor 1: ";
            cin >> flav1;
            cout << "Enter flavor 2: ";
            cin >> flav2;
            cout << "Enter flavor 3: ";
            cin >> flav3;
            cout << " ( " << flav1 << " )" << endl;
            cout << " ( " << flav2 << " )" << endl;
            cout << " ( " << flav3 << " )" << endl;
            cout << "  \\"
                 << " /" << endl << "   |" << endl;
        }
        if (numberofscoops == 2) {
            cout << "Enter flavor 1: ";
            cin >> flav1;
            cout << "Enter flavor 2: ";
            cin >> flav2;
            cout << " ( " << flav1 << " )" << endl;
            cout << " ( " << flav2 << " )" << endl;
            cout << "  \\"
                 << " /" << endl << "   |" << endl;
        }

        if (numberofscoops == 1) {
            cout << "Enter a flavor: ";
            cin >> flav1;
            cout << " ( " << flav1 << " )" << endl;
            cout << "  \\"
                 << " /" << endl << "   |" << endl;
        }
    }

    price(numcones, numberofscoops);
}

int main() {
    int numberofcones;
    int numberofscoops;

    welcome();

    cout << "How many cones would you like?(10 max) ";
    cin >> numberofcones;
    checkcones(numberofcones);
    while (checkcones(numberofcones) == false) {
        cout << "You are not allowed to buy more than 10 cones and you cannot "
                "buy less than one cone.     Please try again.\n";
        cout << "How many cones would you like?(10 max): ";
        cin >> numberofcones;
        checkcones(numberofcones);
    }
    cout << "You are buying " << numberofcones << " ice cream cones.\n";
    buildcone(numberofcones);
}
```

Comment: Your `price` function doesn't use the `cones` argument at all.  Perhaps you should pass in the total so far instead.  Also, can't you think of a better way to handle (75 cents for each additional scoop)?  Besides that, your `welcome()` function, your `price()` function, and your problem description all disagree on the price of a 2 scoop cone.

Answer (score 0):

Your while() loop is flawed.  Comment your call to checkcones() as shown below.  You're already calling checkcones() as the conditional in your while(), no need to evaluate again as this will sent you into a perma-loop.  You've got two of these while() statements that I could see, you'll want to comment out both.

```
while ( checkcones( numberofcones ) == false )
{
    cout << "You are not allowed to buy more than 10 cones and you cannot buy less than one cone.     Please try again.\n";
    cout << "How many cones would you like?(10 max): ";
    cin >> numberofcones;

//    THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM  :)
//    checkcones(numberofcones);
}
```

After this fix, your program begins to work but the pricing fails.  You should be able to figure that out with the answer given above.

I would also see if you can figure out how to implement a c++ class with members and methods as your current approach is very "c" like.  Happy coding!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Start by changing the **return value** of `price()` to *float*, or the function won't be able to return the proper cost. Also, since `cones` is not used to compute the cost of the purchase, we don't it as a `parameter`:

```
float price(int numberofscoops) 
{
    float total_cost = 0.0f;

    if (numberofscoops == 1) {
        total_cost = 2.0f;
    }
    else if (numberofscoops == 2) {
        total_cost = 3.0f;
    }
    else if (numberofscoops > 2) {
        total_cost = 5.0f + ((numberofscoops-2) * 0.75f);
    }

    return total_cost;
}
```

You code could have other problems, but I think these changes will let you continue to debug and fix the code on your own.